# List of CloudFormation CognitoEvents for Cognito Identity Pool creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

The AWS Documentation is not helpful it simply says the property for `CognitoEvents` is `String: String`. I found a topic on GitHub suggesting it was `Event: Lambda ARN`, but with no specifics of what the events could be (I would guess something along the lines of `syncTrigger`).

Any idea what the events are to populate the `CognitoEvents` property of the `AWS::Cognito::IdentityPool` template?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ended up guessing `SyncTrigger` and it was correct (capital "S"). Here is an example of the full configuration:

`Type: "AWS::Cognito::IdentityPool"
Properties:
    IdentityPoolName: YourPoolName
    AllowUnauthenticatedIdentities: true | false
    DeveloperProviderName: accounts.example.com
    SupportedLoginProviders:
        graph.facebook.com: xxxx
        accounts.google.com: xxxx-xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
        api.twitter.com: xxxx;xxxx
    CognitoEvents:
        SyncTrigger: Lambda Function ARN`

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: mark your answer as correct please. it is well deserved